# Error: \"json-to-properties\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: json, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to convert json to .properties, for which I got one utility, however on docker it is not working. Saw many answers on Stackoverflow but of no luck.

```
sh "docker run --rm -v ${workspace}:/tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}':Z -w /tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}' artifactoryUrl/node:10-latest npm init -y"
sh "docker run --rm -v ${workspace}:/tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}':Z -w /tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}' artifactoryUrl/node:10-latest npm install json-to-properties -g"
sh "docker run --rm -v ${workspace}:/tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}':Z -w /tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}' artifactoryUrl/node:10-latest json-to-properties ${WORKSPACE}/app-page.json"
```

Error

**docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec:\"json-to-properties\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.**

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because on every command you are creating a different container, so when you execute this part
`sh "docker run --rm -v ${workspace}:/tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}':Z -w /tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}' artifactoryUrl/node:10-latest json-to-properties ${WORKSPACE}/app-page.json"` the container doesn't have any previous modification.

Could you try this?

```
sh "docker run --rm -itd --name nmp.container -v ${workspace}:/tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}':Z -w /tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}' artifactoryUrl/node:10-latest"
sh "docker exec -it nmp.container sh -c 'npm init -y'"
sh "docker exec -it nmp.container sh -c 'npm install json-to-properties -g'"
sh "docker exec -it nmp.container sh -c 'json-to-properties ${WORKSPACE}/app-page.json'"
```

Comment: Thanks @kevs for sharing the answer, I got few other errors using the above code..but able to solve with the info you gave(the container doesn't have any previous modification.)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of information @kevs gave i.e. the container doesn't have any previous modification. I did a work around, I gave the command in a single line using `&&`
One more issue was with the utility, if no json is found, it doesn't fail or no error message is thrown. I am sure might not be the best way to fix. Let me know the better way to implement the same. Thanks

```
sh "docker run --rm -v ${workspace}'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}':/tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}':Z -w /tmp/'${params.SOURCE_PROPERTY}' docker.artifactory/node:10-latest npm init -y && json-to-properties -g && json-to-properties ${WORKSPACE}/app-page.json"
```